# How to run background functions with Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I'm developing a Flask application in which the user will send an Excel file with the customer's data, will take the information from each line to create a user, the system works with 40,000 customers in each file. So how is it possible to make the Client, when submitting the file, create Clients in the background without interfering with the user's ability to use the application?

`

```
def create_client(data, institution):
        for i in data:
            c = {
                "documents": False,
                "nb": str(i[0]).strip("[]"),
                "cpf": i[1],
                "rg": i[2],
                "name": i[3],
                "birth_date": i[4],
                "mother": i[5],
                "species": i[6],
                "wage": i[7].replace(".", ","),
                "address": i[8],
                "neighborhood": i[9],
                "cep": i[10],
                "city": i[11],
                "state": i[12],
                "phone": i[13],
                "dib": i[14],
                "bank": i[15],
                "agency": i[16],
                "account": i[17],
                "institution": institution,
                "status": "awaiting_inclusion",
                "upload_date": datetime.now(),
                "update_date": datetime.now(),
                "obs": i[18],
            }

            c = Clients(**c)

            try:
                db.session.add(c)
                db.session.commit()
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                client, fisrt_name = Client.consult_client(cpf=i[1])
                flash(
                    f"ATTENTION < The Client <{i[3]}> has the same CPF as the Client <{client.name}>. That's why it wasn't imported."
                )
        return True
```

`

I hope that the user, after sending the Excel file through the input, can access other functions of the system without having to wait to create all the clients, and this creation will occur in the background.

`

```
<div class="form" id="post-register-form">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/import/import-base">
                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <h3>To import the records use the Model on the side &lsaquo; <a href="/export/model-base"
                                class="danger">CLICK HERE</a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <label for="files">Archive:</label>
                            {{ form.files(accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
                            application/vnd.ms-excel") }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="send-button btn-alert">
                        <button type="submit"><span>Import</span></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Making a POST request using an HTML form in this way would block the UI until the server responds. To make an asynchronous POST request, you must leverage Javascript to submit the form via an AJAX request. It generally goes like this:

1. Add an id to the submit button on your form. For instance, `id="submitBtn"`.
2. Attach a Javascript function to your submit button that runs on the `submit` or '`click` events. Be sure it stops the web browser from submitting the form for you by using something like:

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // The rest of your code goes here
  // Consider the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file
  // Send your CSRF token via the X-CSRFToken header
});
```

3. Implement another Flask endpoint whose sole purpose is to receive an AJAX request.